# error when building with cmake using C:\project\libresample_flutter\android\CMakeLists.txt: Build command failed

Tags: android, flutter, dart, ffi

I use package ffi in flutter but when building with cmake: error exception ,Whatever I searched for, I did not find how to fix this error

Execution failed for task ':libresample_flutter:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.

> [CXX1405] error when building with cmake using C:\project\libresample_flutter\android\CMakeLists.txt: Build command failed

````
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
    
    add_library( native_libresample
    
                 SHARED
    
                 ../ios/Classes/filterkit.c ../ios/Classes/lrsexport.c ../ios/Classes/resample.c ../ios/Classes/resamplesubs.c )```
    
    and gradle:
    ```group 'io.swhh.libresample_flutter'
    version '1.0'
    
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        }
    }
    
    rootProject.allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 31
    
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 16
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        lintOptions {
            disable 'InvalidPackage'
        }
      externalNativeBuild {
        // Encapsulates your CMake build configurations.
        cmake {
          // Provides a relative path to your CMake build script.
          path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
      }
    }
````

and flutter.dart

```
    import 'dart:ffi';
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'dart:math';
    import 'dart:typed_data';
    
    
    /*
    'C' Header definition
    void* lrs_open(WORD highQuality,
                   double minFactor,
                   double maxFactor) {
     */
    typedef lrs_open_func = Pointer<Void> Function(Int32, Double, Double);
    typedef LrsOpen = Pointer<Void> Function(int, double, double);
    
    /*
    'C' Header definition
    void lrs_close(void *handle) {
     */
    typedef lrs_close_func = Void Function(Pointer<Void>);
    typedef LrsClose = void Function(Pointer<Void>);
    
    /*
    'C' Header definition
    WORD lrs_process(void *handle,
                    double factor,
                    float *inBuffer,
                    WORD inBufferLen,
                    WORD lastFlag,
                    WORD *inBufferUsed,
                    float *outBuffer,
                    WORD outBufferLen) {
     */
    typedef lrs_process_func = Int32 Function(
      Pointer<Void>,
      Double,
      Pointer<Float>,
      Int32,
      Int32,
      Pointer<Int32>,
      Pointer<Float>,
      Int32,
    );
    typedef LrsProcess = int Function(
      Pointer<Void>,
      double,
      Pointer<Float>,
      int,
      int,
      Pointer<Int32>,
      Pointer<Float>,
      int,
    );
    
 
    class LibresampleFlutter {
      static LibresampleFlutter? _instance;
    
      LrsOpen? _lrsOpen;
      LrsClose? _lrsClose;
      LrsProcess? _lrsProcess;
    
      factory LibresampleFlutter() {
        if (_instance == null) {
          _instance = LibresampleFlutter._();
        }
        return _instance!;
      }
    
      LibresampleFlutter._() {
        final DynamicLibrary nativeLrsLib = Platform.isAndroid
            ? DynamicLibrary.open("libnative_libresample.so")
            : DynamicLibrary.process();
    
        _lrsOpen = nativeLrsLib
            .lookup<NativeFunction<lrs_open_func>>('lrs_open')
            .asFunction();
    
        _lrsClose = nativeLrsLib
            .lookup<NativeFunction<lrs_close_func>>('lrs_close')
            .asFunction();
    
        _lrsProcess = nativeLrsLib
            .lookup<NativeFunction<lrs_process_func>>('lrs_process')
            .asFunction();
      }
    }
    
  
    class Resampler {
      double? _maxFactor;
    
      Pointer<Void>? _nativeInstance;
      var _closed = false;
    
     Pointer<Int32>? _inUsed = allocate();
    
      Pointer<Float>? _inBuf;
      var _inLen = 0;
    
      Pointer<Float>? _outBuf;
      var _outLen = 0;
    
 
     [process]. If
      /// a fixed refactoring factor is required they may be the same.
      ///
      /// The [highQuality] setting makes the resample create more filters, leading
      /// to better quality output.
      Resampler(bool highQuality, double minFactor, double maxFactor) {
        _maxFactor = maxFactor;
        _nativeInstance = LibresampleFlutter()._lrsOpen!(
          highQuality ? 1 : 0,
          minFactor,
          maxFactor,
        );
      }
    
      void _ensureBuffers(int inSize) {
        // output buffer needs to be factor * input buffer
        var outSize = (inSize * _maxFactor!).ceil();
        // plus some for luck
        outSize += min(100, (outSize * 0.1).ceil());
    
        // if (_inLen == 0) {
        //   _inLen = inSize;
        //   _inBuf = allocate<Float>(count: inSize);
        // } else if (inSize > _inLen) {
        //   free(_inBuf);
        //   _inLen = inSize;
        //   _inBuf = allocate<Float>(count: inSize);
        // }
        //
        // if (_outLen == 0) {
        //   _outLen = outSize;
        //   _outBuf = allocate<Float>(count: outSize);
        // } else if (outSize > _outLen) {
        //   free(_outBuf);
        //   _outLen = outSize;
        //   _outBuf = allocate<Float>(count: outSize);
        // }
      }
    
    
      Float32List? process(double factor, Float32List input, bool last) {
        if (_closed) {
          throw Exception('already closed');
        }
    
       // _ensureBuffers(input.length);
        _inBuf!.asTypedList(_inLen).setRange(0, input.length, input);
    
        var processed = LibresampleFlutter()._lrsProcess!(
          _nativeInstance!,
          factor,
          _inBuf!,
          input.length,
          last ? 1 : 0,
          _inUsed!,
          _outBuf!,
          _outLen,
        );
    
        if (processed <= 0) {
          print('hmmm $processed');
          return null;
        }
    
        var output = Float32List(processed);
        output.setRange(0, processed, _outBuf!.asTypedList(_outLen));
    
        return output;
      }
    
      /// Closes the resampler and frees its native resources.
      void close() {
        if (!_closed) {
          LibresampleFlutter()._lrsClose!(_nativeInstance!);
          _closed = true;
        }
      }
    
      static Pointer<Int32>? allocate() {
        return null;
      }
    }
    
   [inputStream.moveNext()]
    /// until that returns [false] at the end of the audio.
    class ResamplerStream {
      double _factor;
      Resampler? _resampler;
      Iterator<Float32List>? inputStream;
    
      /// Creates a wrapper around a resampler with an [Iterator] as input and an
      /// [Iterable] as output.
      ///
      /// See [Resampler] for an explanation of [_factor] and [highQuality].
      ResamplerStream(this._factor, bool highQuality) {
        _resampler = Resampler(highQuality, _factor, _factor);
      }
    
      /// Sets the input of this audio block to the [Iterator]
      void setInputStream(Iterator<Float32List> stream) {
        inputStream = stream;
      }
    
      /// Retrieves the [Iterable] that can be used by the next block in the chain.
      Iterable<Float32List?> getOutputStream() sync* {
        while (true) {
          if (!inputStream!.moveNext()) break;
          yield _resampler!.process(_factor, inputStream!.current, false);
        }
      }
    }
```

and main.dart

```
    import 'dart:typed_data';
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'dart:async';
    
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:libresample_flutter/libresample_flutter.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        var resampler = Resampler(true, 2, 2);
        resampler.process(2, Float32List(160), false);
        resampler.process(2, Float32List(160), false);
        resampler.process(2, Float32List(160), false);
        resampler.process(2, Float32List(160), false);
        resampler.process(2, Float32List(160), true);
        resampler.close();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Text('Testing'),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Thanks for helping me